Aggregating/displaying rows from multiple lists into master list
I am trying to combine the rows from multiple lists to show in a master list. I have seen a few posts about doing similar things in older posts, but none of the answers seem to be active and applicable for my current use.
I have around 6 separate lists for different (lets call them companies), but I want my team to be able to view all items from each of the 6 companies lists without having to individually view all 6 lists.
Requirements

They should be able to edit rows in the master lists and have the edits be displayed in original company’s lists.
Edits of rows in company’s lists will also be displayed in the master list.

Based on older answers and things I've seen online I'm assuming I'll have to use power automate to check for when an item is added to a list but then I don't see/understand how I can have those items added to a master list from that trigger...
Thank you for all so much for your help everyone.

Are you familiar with creating pages and adding 'web parts' to a page?  If you added a web part for each list to a single page, your team could edit all 6 lists from the same page.

I don't quite know from your question why you need a master list, as you didn't give a reason, but perhaps the same thing can be achieved by creating a page with 6x web parts.  Perhaps you just want to see all of your list data in one place?
Example of a page displaying data from 3x lists (1. BF Rehousing: Preferences & Outcomes, 2. Moving Tracker, 3. Disturbance Allowance Cost).

Additional info
Perhaps it is interesting for you to know that you can configure the page so that you can filter on a single value in each list e.g. filter on Company Name.

